# Ionic ios App is not loading from another app

Tags: ios, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I have 2 ionic app, build and deployed in ios and works without any issue.

I am opening one app from another and url scheme and other things are set correctly. When app is opened in background and open that app from another, it opens.

But when app is not opened and tried to open it, it redirect to new app but images and css doesn't load. It was working earlier. But when migrated the app from Ionic 2 to 3, it stopped working.

```
 let app: string;
if (Device.platform === 'iOS') {
  app = iosSchemaName;
  let browser = new InAppBrowser(app, '_system');
} else if (Device.platform === 'Android') {
  app = androidPackageName;

} else {

  let browser = new InAppBrowser(httpUrl, '_system');
  return;
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did anyone find solution?

Comment: I am facing the same problem . Any solution ?